# Do nodejs have have list (collection) as in java

Tags: arrays, node.js, list, collections

Does nodejs have list collection - similar dynamic arrays concept. I require a dynamic array type concept in my nodejs coding. Is there any concept like list or any similar ones in nodejs?
 My code is shown below, I would like to use a list like concept than using array... any options like list,  map in

```
first(){
   var msg ='first'
   sendMsg(msg)
}
second(){
   var msg ='first'
   sendMsg(msg)
}
third(){
   var msg ='first'
   sendMsg(msg)
}

sendMsg(msg){
   var msgArr = []; 
   for(var i in msgArr)
   msgArr[i]= msg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are looking to do but from what I understand you are looking to push the messages into a container that holds all of the sent messages correct? However, at your present setup, you are overwriting the existing array with an empty array every time you are calling sendMsg(). If you want to keep an array of messages then you have to create a global array and use .push() in your sendMsg function. See below:

```
const msgArr = [];

function first(){
   var msg ='first'
   sendMsg(msg)
}

function second(){
   var msg ='second'
   sendMsg(msg)
}

function third(){
   var msg ='third'
   sendMsg(msg)
}

function sendMsg(msg){
   msgArr.push(msg);
}

first();
second();
third();
```

More on arrays and sets here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

I hope this helps!